# Gradle 4.10.2 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6 when running gradle from commandline

Tags: java, gradle, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to learn gradle build.

I followed this link to install gradle and i followed the steps mentioned it.
https://gradle.org/install/#close-notification
After successfully following all steps i am not able to run gradle from command line.
I am using Ubuntu system.

```
gradle -v

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle 4.10.2 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

So after uninstalling and installing back and forth still stuck in this position.

And it shows it requires Java7 and i checked it out with command

```
java -version
```

and got this output.

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

so i dont know how to go ahead.

Comment: It might be a JAVA_HOME variable having been set (`echo $JAVA_HOME`) or not set.

Comment: @JoopEggen man ur awesome!!while issueing command in terminal points to my java1.6 sdk

Comment: @JoopEggen Please post that as answer

Comment: @JoopEggen i was banging my head this much time whether to ask or not!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a JAVA_HOME variable having been set (`echo $JAVA_HOME`) or not set.